# HDFS Daemon - java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am getting the following error while formatting name node. Please let me know what could be the reason and how to go about solving this ?

```
20/09/11 12:30:59 WARN net.DNS: Unable to determine local hostname -falling back to "localhost"
java.net.UnknownHostException: 45.77.87.29.vultr.com: 45.77.87.29.vultr.com: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1506)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.resolveLocalHostname(DNS.java:264)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.<clinit>(DNS.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newBlockPoolID(NNStorage.java:982)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newNamespaceInfo(NNStorage.java:591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:175)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:1015)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1457)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1582)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 45.77.87.29.vultr.com: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1501)
        ... 8 more
20/09/11 12:30:59 WARN net.DNS: Unable to determine address of the host-falling back to "localhost" address
java.net.UnknownHostException: 45.77.87.29.vultr.com: 45.77.87.29.vultr.com: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1506)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.resolveLocalHostIPAddress(DNS.java:287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.<clinit>(DNS.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newBlockPoolID(NNStorage.java:982)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newNamespaceInfo(NNStorage.java:591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:175)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:1015)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1457)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1582)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 45.77.87.29.vultr.com: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1501)
        ... 8 more
```